# How should I change the vertical spacing between glossary entries?

Tags: spacing, glossaries, glossaries-extra

What is the easiest or best way to change vertical spacing between all glossary entries at once, without affecting the rest of the document?  This must be an elementary question, but I'm having trouble finding the answer in the documentation for the glossaries and glossaries-extra packages ([here](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf) and [here](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.pdf), respectively), as well as elsewhere on Stack Exchange.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Glossary}
\setglossarypreamble{\noindent This is a glossary.}
\newglossaryentry{cba}{name={cba},
description={definition of cba}}
\newglossaryentry{bca}{name={bca},
description={definition of bca}}
\newglossaryentry{abc}{name={abc},
description={definition of abc}}
\glsaddall

\begin{document}
The main text of the document.

\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default glossary style is in fact a `description` environment, and uses the default spacing of list enviromnments. The spacing between items is `\itemsep+\parsep`. Unfortunately this is defined in the macro `\@listi`, which you could redefine, but this is ugly as you have to use `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`.

You could define your own glossary style with `\newglossarystyle`, but that seems to me to be overkill in this situation. Simpler would be to just redefine environment `theglossary` and use a kind of modified `description`(like) environment. For example if you want to eliminate the vertical space between the entries:

```
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{list}{}
      {%
        \setlength\labelwidth{0pt}%
        \setlength\itemindent{-\leftmargin}%
        \setlength\itemsep{0pt}%
        \setlength\parsep{0pt}%
        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}%
      }
      {\end{list}}
```

[image]