# Reduce vertical space between acronyms in printed glossary

Tags: formatting, white-space, glossary

I would like to reduce the whitespace between the acronyms in a printed glossary. In the below example, there is a lot of whitespace between "**DD** domain decomposition" and "**PDE** partial differential equation". How can I reduce the whitespace between these acronyms in the printed glossary resulting from `\printglossary`?

Page 240 of the [user manual](https://mirrors.evoluso.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) details options of the `\printglossary` command, but I didn't see anything related to whitespace.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym[plural=PDEs]{pde}{PDE}{partial differential equation}
\newacronym{dd}{DD}{domain decomposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
    Here is some interesting stuff about \glspl{pde} and \gls{dd}.
\end{abstract}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example working code for the above question is given below (it is based off another [TeX post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598694/how-should-i-change-the-vertical-spacing-between-glossary-entries)):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym, nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{list}{}
      {%
        \setlength\labelwidth{0pt}%
        \setlength\itemindent{-\leftmargin}%
        \setlength\itemsep{0pt}%
        \setlength\parsep{0pt}%
        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}%
      }
      {\end{list}}
      
\makeglossaries

\newacronym[plural=PDEs]{pde}{PDE}{partial differential equation}
\newacronym{dd}{DD}{domain decomposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
    Here is some interesting stuff about \glspl{pde} and \gls{dd}.
\end{abstract}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

[image]